# How do I submit a form with limit_validation_errors?

Tags: forms

I want to create a node. If users put something in the required field, it will show an error message; if users don't put any value in the required field, the node will be saved without the required field.

Comment: is it custom form or content type?

Comment: Any reason for not removing the required option?

Comment: It is content type actually i have used workbench with some user with role for particular role i want node as a draft for some role. if node published then i will use required fields.

Comment: It doesn't make sense: First you are showing the field as required, and then showing an error if the field contains a value. It would make sense for a kind of test for human beings filling a form, but I don't know if that make sense in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you're saying, I think you should not put this field as a "required field" as the field can be empty.

So what I would do is:

- set the field has not required
- add a custom validation function that checks, if the field is not empty, that the submitted value validates your requirements. You should look at the [hook_field_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7) or [hook_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_validate/7) to add your custom validation

Comment: it is fine when we have few fields but in my case i have approx hundreds field.i have used one solution but it is making node with out any values./**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  
  if($form['#bundle']=='catalog'){
    if (isset($form['actions']['submit'])) {
      $form['actions']['submit']['#limit_validation_errors']=array();
      }
   }
  }

Comment: @Fawwad Don't use comments to show code; if the code is relevant to answer the question, show it in the question itself.

Comment: Also, having 100s fields don't change the approach; what said from Matt is still true and applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with the question though but if your issue is to allow a certain user role to use a particular field and not by other user roles than probably the way should be to not show/hide that field on the basis of field accessibility for user roles.

In the above mentioned use case [Field Permission](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module can be helpful.

Comment: if i want to make node in draft state then i want to skip required filed validation.How to do it?

Comment: the module I have mentioned will not work for the draft or publish state, it will work if draft is created by a different user role and then publish by different user role, as the module sets permissions for fields on user role basis.